# Retrieve without iterating from a SingletonMap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-6

I have created a method that return me a Map which is singleton Map as below

```
@Override
protected Map<String,String> getFavTypeCd()
{
   final Map<String,String> favType = Collections.singletonMap("1","first");
   return favType;
}
```

I was looking for a way , that I could extract the value for the above Map without iterating. Any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Did you try `favType.get("1")`?

Comment: Yes it will.  The [`get` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) is the way to retrieve a value via a key.

Comment: @user1993412 What are you talking about? That's *exactly* how you retrieve a value from a `Map`

Comment: @BrianRoach , How Can we do that based on the key directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the easiest is to directly make use of the key to get value

```
 favTypeCd.get("1") returns "First"
```